# One select for multiple records by composite key

Tags: sql

Such a query as in the title would look like this I guess:

```
select * from table t where (t.k1='apple' and t.k2='pie') or (t.k1='strawberry' and t.k2='shortcake') 
... --10000 more key pairs here
```

This looks quite verbose to me. Any better alternatives? (Currently using SQLite, might use MYSQL/Oracle.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use for example this on Oracle, i assume that if you use regular concatenate() instead of Oracle's || on other DB, it would work too (as it is simply just a string comparison with the IN list). Note that such query might have suboptimal execution plan.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  TABLE t
WHERE
  t.k1||','||t.k2 IN ('apple,pie',
                      'strawberry,shortcake' );
```

But if you have your value list stored in other table, Oracle supports also the format below.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  TABLE t
WHERE (t.k1,t.k2) IN ( SELECT x.k1, x.k2 FROM x );
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about your second solution, but another 100k row table that will grow in the future for a small app seems too resource intensive. As for the first, you suggest that generating the code for my original approach is better in terms of performance?

Comment: I wouldn't be too sure, massive OR list doesn't hints anything good. Try also solution suggested by Ronnis, if it works on your DB. I've tried it and it apparently works on Oracle too.

Answer (score 4):

Don't be afraid of verbose syntax. Concatenation tricks can easily mess up the selectivity estimates or even prevent the database from using indexes.

Here is another syntax that may or may not work in your database.

```
select * 
  from table t 
 where (k1, k2) in(
            ('apple',      'pie')
           ,('strawberry', 'shortcake')
           ,('banana',     'split')
           ,('raspberry',  'vodka')
           ,('melon',      'shot')
       );
```

A final comment is that if you find yourself wanting to submit 1000 values as filters you should most likely look for a different approach all together :)

Comment: sql server does not support this, can you please give an example RDBMS which supports above syntax thanks

Comment: Oracle supports this syntax.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from table t 
where (t.k1+':'+t.k2) 
in ('strawberry:shortcake','apple:pie','banana:split','etc:etc')
```

This will work in most of the cases as it concatenate and finds in as one column

off-course you need to choose a proper separator which will never come in the value of k1 and k2.
for e.g. if k1 and k2 are of type int you can take any character as separator

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName t
WHERE t.k1=( CASE WHEN t.k2=VALUE THEN someValue 
                  WHEN t.k2=otherVALUE THEN someotherValue END)
```

[- SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9b0e/1)

Comment: I don't completely understand this unfortunately... How this handles multiple composite keys?

Comment: I have tested above query for SQL Server . I am considering a general scenario where table has two columns k1 and k2.

Comment: Ok got it. Unfortunately this still grows with the size of the input. Is there any way to do this with `in` so the only growing part is the input?